# Why Binary file is not a Text file and all Text files are Binary files?

Tags: c

What is the deciding factor for classifying a file into Binary or Text file?

E.g: 
Consider the below C program

1. Create file in **binary** mode
2. Write two integers into file "binary.txt".

NOTE: Before running the program make sure binary.txt doesnt exist.

Observation:

File created "binary.txt" with contents TEXTFILE

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int arr[2] = {1415071060,1162627398};
   FILE *fp = fopen("binary.txt", "wb");

   if(fp == NULL)
   {
       printf("Error opening file\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   fwrite(arr, sizeof(arr), 1, fp);
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

However only creator knows that it is created in binary mode and this should be called binary file.

Anyone who opens the file "binary.txt" think its **text** file.

What a general user should call this file - **Binary** or **Text** file?

Comment: Because text is composed of readable / printable symbols which are a **proper subset** of *all* of the available symbols. As for the programs/scripts you better research a bit about the difference between scripting/interpreted and compiled languages.

Comment: There is a tremendous difference between "binary" and "executable".  There are executable files that afford interpretation as text (i.e. would not normally be considered binary), and files that do not support interpretation as text that nevertheless are not executable.  The two concepts are pretty much orthogonal.

Comment: In any case, text *vs.* binary is not a fundamental file characteristic on modern operating systems, but rather a differentiation between how files are *interpreted*.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**NOTE:** Limiting our discussion to ASCII (multi-byte charsets, other Encodings are set aside to avoid unnecessary confusion)

---

Let us understand the difference between string and array of characters

In a byte of `8 bits`, we can store `0 to 255` if *unsigned*, `-128 to +127` if *signed*

As a whole, if we see a byte (`8 bits`) the value that can be fit into it is `-128 to 255` (range). The range of ASCII characters (`0 to 127`).

Given character array `a[10]` if any of the bytes `a[0] to a[9]` has value out of the range of ASCII character range then it is not a **string**, its just array of characters. If all of the bytes fall within the ASCII range (`0 to 127`) then it is **string**.

In summary for the array of characters, the range can be any of (`-128 to 255`).

Important conclusion here is since ASCII range (`0 to 127`) is a proper subset of `-128 to 255` All **strings** can be called the array of characters.

Now let us apply the above definition to ***binary*** file vs **text** file.

If in a file all bytes are in the range of ASCII (`0 to 127`) it should be called a **text** file.

If any of them falls out of this range i.e any of `(-128 to -1`) or (`128 to 255`) then it is a **binary** file.

In summary, since ASCII range `0 to 127` is a proper subset of (`-128 to 255`) **all text files are binary files**.

If a file has atleast one byte from (`-128 to -1`) or (`128 to 255`) **it cannot be text file only binary file**.

I have not verified standards if any of ASCII range character(s) has special treatment. But in summary I think I made the distinction behind **text file** vs **binary file** clear.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is incorrect and does not address the OP's question. The combined range of signed and unsigned byte values is adding the the confusion on a subject that is already too subtle: `char` can be signed or unsigned by default. Text files need not be ASCII files, and they usually contain non printable bytes: LF (and CR). By your definition "Hello world\n" is not a string. Various encodings use byte values with a much wider range than ASCII, yet text encoded in these still constitute text files.

Comment: For simplicity I made a note above that Iam not considering multi-byte charsets and limiting to ASCII text files. If I bring them in the definition is really complicated. I agree that the ranges I mentioned are not accurate and I will correct them.

Comment: The above answered my question and to be frank this is exactly what iam looking for. The range of numbers in each set as @chqrlie pointed out may not be accurate, however files are categorized by value in each byte not how interpreters understand the text in your file, is the message i liked.

Comment: *"If in a file all bytes are in the range of <something> it should be called a text file"* This is VERY wrong.

Comment: Apparently you have never used UTF-8, or windows-1252 or iso-8859-1 (etc) encoded text files, your explanation makes no sense.

Comment: For what it's worth, the range of values of `signed char` is [-128, +127], not [-127, +127].

Comment: @klutt "If in a file all bytes are in the range of <something> it should be called a text file" is the ONLY definition for **Text** file. Anything else is wrong.

Comment: @Prathibha So if I make a text file containing _all_ the characters in a certain character set, encoded with a certain character encoding, it is not a text file? (I think your points address guessing if a file is a text file or guessing the encoding of a text file. In other words, coping with inadequate data management practices that have lost metadata. If that is part of your question, please [edit] it.)

Comment: @Tom Exactly thats the point, If Encoding is different then the range is different(map the code units with ASCII text range and form set X). But the fundemental point is same if all bytes fall in this set X then it is **text** file. If you see the NOTE above, it is clearly mentioned that he is restricting to ascii only.
To explain this basic point we need not consider multi-byte character sets, other encodings. To complicate further if you see ASCII text file with different encoding it may be binary.

Comment: @Prathibha No, not all character encodings emit/allow arbitrary sequences of the byte values they use so a range test is inadequate for validity. And, no, just because a file is can be successfully decoded as a text file with a particular character encoding doesn't make it a text file. In fact, every file can be successfully decoded as a text file with many character encodings. (There are probably ASCII files somewhere in my system but I would be hard-pressed to identify one. Text files are rarely designed, written and read as ASCII. MSDOS didn't have an ASCII code page. Windows got one late.)

Comment: By this answer, the string `"\001\002\003\004\005"` is ASCII text, and a file containing those bytes would be a text file.  Most people would say otherwise, however.

Answer (score 11):

@JohnBollinger summarized it best in a comment.

> text vs. binary is not a fundamental file characteristic on modern operating systems, but rather a differentiation between how files are *interpreted*.

Let's say a file contains four bytes with the following hex values of the bytes:

```
0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44
```

If you interpret those bytes as characters in a system that uses ASCII encoding, you will get the characters `ABCD`.

If you treat those bytes as a 4-byte integer, you will get the value `0x41424344` (1094861636 in decimal) in a big endian system and `0x44434241` (1145258561 in decimal) in a little endian system.

As far as the computer is concerned, it's all binary. As to what they mean, it's all a matter of intepretation.

Comment: Perhaps the best example of this is the EICAR test virus which is the following string: `X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*`  which is composed entirely of printable ASCII characters.  However, under 16 bit MSDOS, if that were saved as a file that was given a .COM extension, it would run as a program that announced itself.

Answer (score 4):

On modern operating systems, there is no distinction at the file system level between text files and binary files. On legacy systems, the C library implements a series of tricks to translate newlines between OS specific representations (such as `0x0D` `0x0A`) and the single byte representation '`\n'` for the C program reading the file in *text mode*. This compatibility layer must not be used when dealing with actual binary contents, for which the `b` option must be used in `fopen()`.

Older operating systems used to have different representations for text and binary files, but most of these are obsolete nowadays.

Conversely, many file systems keep track of executable files with some specific information such as mode bits on Unix FS. These executable files can be binary, containing one form or another of executable code, while others are text files containing scripts.

In your example, whether the file should be seen as *binary* or *text* is a matter of intent. If the *creator* of the file intended for is to be read as binary, naming it `binary.txt` is confusing as the filename extension `.txt` is routinely used to indicate generic text files. `sample.bin` would be much more obvious.

How to interpret the contents of a file is important for programmers and casual users: on legacy systems, loading and save a file as text may change its contents, unless you use tools that are terminally anal about preserving contents.

For example **qemacs**, a programmer's editor inspired by emacs, makes extensive efforts upon loading a file to determine the best mode for displaying and editing the contents:

- binary vs: text mode (defaulting to hex display for binary)
- line termination convention
- character encoding
- programming language or other specific content sensitive display options...

If the file is written back without modifications, the contents are preserved so binary files that happen to have textual contents are unmodified. Otherwise, the above tests determine the correct conventions for encoding new contents.

Comment: Keeping all (encoding, locale, machine, creator, user, etc) fixed i.e using only ASCII encoding, etc, so are you saying we cannot define text file based on what bytes it contain

Comment: What I am saying is you can use contents to determine what format a file appears to have, but how the file contents are interpreted by a given program may be more subtle. Changing the line termination scheme may seem innocuous for an ASCII text file, but some programs will fail to display it properly (for example Notepad does not handle text files with unix style line endings correctly).

Comment: Will you agree with me on this - Fixed encoding ASCII, locale, machine, etc if I save single character 'a' in it - it can be called text file (remember all text files are binary files)

Comment: @SudhakarMNSR: such a file with a single byte `a` looks like a malformed text file because it does not have a newline sequence. Its contents is textual but it could also be a binary file with the number 97 encoded on a single byte. If the file contained 2 bytes `0x61 0x0a` or 3 bytes `0x61 0x0d 0x0a`, the textual nature of the file would be reinforced.

Comment: @chqrlie "Its contents is textual but it could also be a binary file" please clarify whether you are disagreeing with my statement "all files are binary files". If you disagree can you give me an example to say when/which file is not binary (Fixed encoding, locale, machine, OS, etc)

Comment: @chqrlie if you say character 'a' followed by newline is text file (as of today). But what if someone develop new editor where charater 'a' is some formatting command and in this editor "a\n" displays something else.. so now is "a/n" still text file?

Comment: @SudhakarMNSR: I did not say it *was* a text file, I wrote its contents is textual, which is a fact. Yet this contents may very well be interpreted in a different way by the program that reads it and altering it as text may have adverse effects.

Answer (score 3):

This question has changed substantially since it was first posed. In particular, the term "executable" has been removed from the discussion.

Current question:

> Only creator knows that it is created in binary mode and this should be called binary file.

The creator has not only created the file but also made it available. If the purpose and format was not communicated then that is a failure somewhere.

> Anyone who opens the file "binary.txt" think it's text file.

People would probably *think* so, but they still can't properly process it as a text file without knowing the character encoding. Again, a communications failure. A guessed-at character encoding that works today might not work for the contents of the file tomorrow.

---

Answer to original question:

Yes, it's all a matter of interpretation. Interpretation requires context and metadata.

In addition to what others have said,

- A file cannot be **text** unless you know which character encoding was used to write it (and must be used to read it). Common file systems do not store this knowledge. People dealing in text files must pass this essential metadata on to programs and other people.
- A file cannot be **executable** unless you know which interpreter program or program loader to load it with. Systems have schemes for this:

  - Unix-like: Set the eXecutable flag on the file in the file system. Then if it is a "script" and an interpreter program is required for it, the script can have a shebang `#!` line stating the program to run it in.
  - Windows: Use a particular file extension listed in the PATHEXT environment variable. Example: `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC` The extension would be registered with an Open verb indicating how to "open" or start it.
  - Finally, the program could have a "file signature" that indicates which program loader to run it with.
- A file can be called **binary** whether or not you have metadata to call it text or executable or both.

Answer (score 2):

I think one has to distinguish "text", "binary", and "executable":

"Text" usually means a file containing only human readable characters (alpha + numeric + tabs and cr/lf), i.e. something that you can open with a text editor without seeing weird stuff.

The meaning of "binary" often depends on the context. If the context is, for example, the open mode used in file processing, then "binary" means that each byte is read in as is, whereas "text" means that platform specific conversions like automatically converting a `"\r\n"` into a single `"\n"` apply (cf., for example, `FILE *fp=fopen("c:\\test.txt", "rb")` versus `FILE *fp=fopen("c:\\test.txt", "rt")`).  If the context is the distribution format of programs, then "binary" often means "precompiled for a particular platform". This is in contrast to source code distributions, where the files are typically "text files".

The meaning of "executable" is that the file content is interpreted by the operating system as an executable program. This often means a file containing machine code instructions, which contain non-readable characters as well, such that they are usually not "text files", and they are usually not interpreted as text. In a broader sense, also shell scripts are "executables", as they contain instructions interpreted by the respective shell. These instructions are written as text and can be opened in a text editor.

From these perspectives, I think that "text" and "binary" are opposite terms, whereas "executable" is orthogonal to both.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking two different questions.

**File contents**

If the file contains textual data, i.e., lines of characters delimited by newlines, then it is a *text* file.

Otherwise it is presumed to contain data in some form other than strictly character data, such as binary integers, floating-point numbers, image pixels, music samples, structured binary data, etc., which means that it is a *binary* file, i.e., a *non-text* file.

There are many other text file formats, such as `.xml`, `.html`, `.csv`, as well as programming language source code files. These are strictly character text files, but generally have some kind of internal structure based on the syntax of their contents.

That being said, all text files are inherently binary files, in the sense that the characters, newlines, and so forth comprising the textual data in the file are nothing more that a stream of bytes at the lowest level.

**File name**

Specifically, the filename *extension* or *suffix*. By convention, files with a `.txt` extension are presumed to contain text data, i.e., lines of character data delimited by some kind of newline sequences.

A different filename extension like `.bin` or `.exe` (or a hundred others) indicate some kind of binary data file, usually structured in some way. By convention, `.bin` indicates binary data with no specific format, i.e., just a stream of bytes.

In addition, there are files having an extension like `.doc` or `.pdf` (or dozens of others), indicating a *word processing document* file. These files also contain character text data, but it is typically stored in some kind of strictly binary format that is specific to the word processing software used to create it.

Answer (score -1):

In general, a file is just a sequence of bytes.

For any machine you're likely to use, bytes are 8 bits.  So each byte has 256 possible values.

Confining our attention for the moment to old-fashioned ASCII. something like 95 of those bytes are ordinary, printing characters: letters, digits, punctuation.  There are a few more characters which may also appear in text files: let's say tab, carriage return, linefeed, and form feed (`'\t'`, `'\r'`, `'\n'`, and `'\f'`).

If every one of the bytes in a file is one of those printing characters, the file is a text file.

If any of the bytes in a file is other than one of those printing characters, the file is not a text file.

If the file is intended for human consumption, its creator will have used only the ordinary printing characters, and it will be a text file.

If the file contains arbitrary data, each byte might have any of its 256 possible values, and the file will be a binary file.  It's very likely that at least one of the bytes in such a file will be something other than an ordinary printing character.  (Even if all the arbitrary bytes just happen to be in the set of ordinary printable characters, they probably won't mean much, and we might still think of it as a binary file.)

Anyway, that's why every text file is theoretically a binary file, but not every binary file is a text file.

As a practical example, try this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short int x = 906;
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("binaryfile.bin", "wb");
    if(fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL) exit(1);
    fprintf(fp1, "%d\n", x);
    fwrite(&x, sizeof(x), 1, fp2);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

If you compile and run this program, you should find that it creates a text file `textfile.txt` containing the string `12345`.  But if you inspect the file `binaryfile.bin`, you should find that it contains just two bytes, with the hexadecimal values `03` and `8A`.  Neither of those is an ordinary printing character, so it's a binary file.

Now, try changing the program slightly, setting

```
short int x = 12345;
```

If you run it again, `textfile.txt` will now contain the string `12345`, as expected.  `binaryfile.bin` will again contain two bytes, this time with hex values `30` and `39`.  But if you try printing `binaryfile.bin`, you'll probably see the characters `0` and `9`, because `0x30` and `0x39` are the ASCII codes for the characters `0` and `9`.